# spring mvc gives an exception as sending your request to the wrong URI 404 message null

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>withDiffServletName</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/sample-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

sample-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.app.simple" />
   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

ConrrollController.java

```
@Component
public class ConrrollController 
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView student() {
          return new ModelAndView("student", "command", "hi");
       }
}
```

index.jsp
url student in href

dear all,
i am new to spring,your small information will encourage me lots
i am getting an exception as
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/withDiffServletName/student] in DispatcherServlet with name 'sample'

please provide me solution i am not getting any thing i tried it in many ways
where i become wrong i am not getting any idea

Comment: Side note: it doesn't make sense to register the same context configuration for both your `DispatcherServlet` and your `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i have removed ContextLoaderListener but same error ,i am fresher so can u explain in my level

Comment: i got an answer i mistake @ component it must be @ controller